# how to use multiple database connections in sails.js?

Tags: database, sails.js

I'm new in sails and I want to know that how can I use multiple database connections and use all of them in my app? now I'm using MySQL but I want to add mongo to add some data to it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this with sails.

**If you are using a version < v1**

First thing to do is add a connection to each db in the connections.js file located in the config folder and ensure they both have a different name.

For example

```
someDBServer1: {
  adapter: 'sails-mongo'
  ...
},

someDbServer2: {
  adapter: 'sails-mysql',
  ...
},
```

Then in each Model, you can set the respective connection. If for example you have your User data stored in one database and your images stored in another.

You can set the connection in the User model like this:

```
module.exports = {
  connection : 'someDBServer1',
  attributes: {...
```

And in the Images model using the other connection:

```
module.exports = {
  connection : 'someMongodbServer2',
  attributes: {...
```

**For sails version >= v1**

The setup is very similar.

Databases are stored in datastores. Datastores are defined in the Sails config config/datastores.js.

Then as above rather than setting the connection in the specific Model, you set the datastore.

For more info on this see [Sails ORM Documentation](https://next.sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm) or [Sails v1 ORM Documentation](https://next.sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm).

Comment: Is it possible to select the connection dynamically while querying from controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can add all of your adapters in your `config/datastores.js`, if you want all of your models use a single adapter, then you just need to change the default model settings in `config/models.js`, if you want to override settings for a particular model, then you need to change the model's definition file.
you can find more informations in the docs here [Model settings](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/model-settings).